# Connect custom domain to firebase hosting -

Tags: firebase-hosting, dreamhost

I am trying to connect custom domain to firebase hosting.
According to firebase guidline, I added TXT records which is generated by them to my DNS provider - DreamHost

But I see this error message

"We couldn't verify your domain totalbodyconsulting.com. Please check your settings and try again."

Would you hint me?

Thanks

Comment: If you want anyone here to help, you'll have to show what Firebase asked you to do, and what you've done on dreamhost in response. Screenshots typically work best for that. You can also [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a few hours for Firebase to get the new DNS records.